# Spring Data JPA offset is inject in the database query but limit is not

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination, spring-data

I am using spring data JPA. I am building a query where I need to limit the query. I am passing the offset and limit value from frontend. When query is executed in the database I see that offset is in the query but limit is not.

It is asking the database to pickup all the  records as offset + limit. It's not similar with raw query limit then. How can I act the limit value as raw query so that the query execution get faster without native query?

My method where I am building the criteria:

```
public List<Role> findAllByRoleNameAndUpdatedBy(String roleName, Integer offset, Integer limit) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
    Root<Role> role = cq.from(Role.class);
    Predicate roleNamePredicate = cb.like(role.get("roleName"), roleName + "%");
    cq.where(roleNamePredicate);
    TypedQuery<Role> query = em.createQuery(cq).setFirstResult(offset) // offset
            .setMaxResults(limit); // limit
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Edit:

My controller method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/list/{roleName}/{offset}/{limit}")
public List<Role> getListDummy(@PathVariable String roleName, @PathVariable Integer offset, @PathVariable Integer limit) {
    return roleServiceDummy.findAllByRoleNameAndUpdatedBy(roleName, offset, limit);
}
```

My API in postman: `localhost:9000/role/list/test_/1000/1`

Generated query in console:

```
select
    top 1001 role0_.id as id1_13_,
    role0_.created_by_id as created_2_13_,
    role0_.created_date as created_3_13_,
    role0_.modified_date as modified4_13_,
    role0_.updated_by_id as updated_5_13_,
    role0_.role_name as role_nam6_13_ 
from
    auth_role role0_ 
where
    role0_.role_name like ?
```

As we can see it is picking all the 1001 rows.

Comment: Not sure if I follow completely but if the table has 100 records, then
`criteria.setMaxResults(25);`  will only fetch 25 records out of 100 records, and
`criteria.setFetchSize(20);`  will fetch 20 records at each time until it reads all 100 records from the table.

Comment: Could you post the generated sql, including bind parameters and the used values for `offset` and `limit`?

Comment: @JensSchauder, I have edited the post and provided the generated query